# DAW Plugins with Multiple Instruments

Tags: daw, ableton-live

I am using Ableton Live Lite with a Focusrite Scarlet and BiasFX. Using this setup with my guitar is great, however when I plug in a second instrument and use the BiasFx plugin only one track has the plugin enabled, the other track is clean.  We had planned to use the Focusrite for joint practice, but only having processing on one instrument is not great.

Is this a limitation of Ableton Live or BiasFX?  Or do I need to alter some settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly isn't a limitation of BiasFX, which is just an effect plugin and you can use use multiple of. It also isn't a limitation of the Focusrite Scarlett, which has two independent inputs. (Not all versions, but that's the standard I think.)

I strongly doubt it is a limitation of Ableton Live either, even the Lite version. You need to set up two tracks, each routed from one of the inputs and each with one instance of BiasFX.

If that doesn't work, switch to another DAW. [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/), albeit not really intended for any live use, would do this just fine.